# Is there a way to get Value show up in Running Total when the table does not have the value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a view with 4 columns and one of them is a running Total. One of the columns- ColB I would usually have A,B and C values per day but somedays only Values A and B are populated. But for the running total I want to see the measure for all the 3 values :A,B and C. following is the logic I am using to get the view.

```
    SELECT  ColA
            ,  Date
            ,  ColB
            ,  RunningTotal 
            ,  CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM DATE)) as monthYear
FROM Table1  
INNER JOIN (  
    SELECT ColA 
            , Date 
            , ColB
            , monthYear 
            , measureA
            , SUM(measureA) OVER(PARTITION BY monthYear, ColA, ColB ORDER BY DATE ASC) as runningTotal
    FROM (
            SELECT ColA
                    , CAST(DATE as DATE) 
                    , ColB
                    , SUM(MeasureA) 
                    , CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM Date),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM Date)) as monthYear
            FROM Table2  
            WHERE CAST(Date as DATE) >= '2020-11-01'
            and ColA = 'Reston'
            GROUP BY ColB, ColA, Date
            ORDER BY ColB, Date ASC
        ) as sub
        GROUP BY ColB, ColA, Date, monthYear
        ORDER BY ColB, Date ASC
    ) as IJ
on CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM .`DATE`),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM .`DATE`)) = IJ.monthYear
AND table1.ColA = IJ.ColA
AND table1.ColB = IJ.ColB
GROUP BY ColA, table1.Date, table1.ColB ,IJ.Date, IJ.monthYear
ORDER BY table1.ColA, table1.ColB, Date ASC
```

Here is how the view currently looks like

```
    ColA       Date         ColB     RunningTotal     
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Reston     2 Nov2020       A        "50000"                
  Reston     2 Nov2020       B        "100000"            
  Reston     2 Nov2020       C        "5000"                  
  Reston     3 Nov2020       A        "100000"           
  Reston     3 Nov2020       B        "200000"       
  Reston     4 Nov2020       A        "150000"             
  Reston     4 Nov2020       B        "300000"              
  Reston     4 Nov2020       C        "10000"
```

on November 3rd you'll notice that there are only A and B values in ColB, due to this there is no running Total on Nov 3rd for C. Instead is there a way in SQL that I could show C in ColB for November3rd with the Nov2nd runningTotal value. like this:

```
   ColA           Date         ColB     RunningTotal     
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Reston        2 Nov2020       A        "50000"                
  Reston        2 Nov2020       B        "100000"            
  Reston        2 Nov2020       C        "5000"                  
  Reston        3 Nov2020       A        "100000"           
  Reston        3 Nov2020       B        "200000"
  Reston        3 Nov2020       C        "5000"       
  Reston        4 Nov2020       A        "150000"             
  Reston        4 Nov2020       B        "300000"              
  Reston        4 Nov2020       C        "10000"
```

This is my first post with Table as an example so sorry for the bad formatting, tried the ASCII table format converters but couldn't get the col | separation.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and provide a [mre]

Comment: Will the view eventually be shown on an app? A web page maybe?

Comment: no this is for internal reporting, it'll be a csv or excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem, it basically required some Create Table Expressions that would store the dates and the values and I then LEFT JOIN it with my main table to get the values show up in the running total.

```
SELECT ColA
, ColB
, date
, monthYear
, MeasureA
, SUM(MeasureA) OVER(PARTITION BY monthYear, ColA, ColB ORDER BY Date ASC) as runningTotal
FROM (  

    SELECT sub1.ColA 
                    , sub1.ColB 
                    , sub1.monthYear
                    , sub1.date
                    , COALESCE(measureA, '0') as measureA
    FROM (
        WITH CTE1 AS ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT ColA
                            , ColB
                            , CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM `Date`),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM `Date`)) as monthYear 
            FROM Table1
            WHERE `Date` >= '2020-11-01'
        ),

        CTE3 AS ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT ColA
                        , Date
                        , CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM `Date`),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM `Date`)) as monthYear
            FROM Table2 
            WHERE CAST(Date as DATE) >= '2020-11-01'
        )

        SELECT DISTINCT a.ColA
                        , a.ColB 
                        , a.monthYear
                        , c.lift_date
        FROM CTE1 a 
        LEFT JOIN CTE3 c 
        on a.ColA = c.ColA 
        AND a.monthYear = c.monthYear
        ) as sub1 
        LEFT JOIN (  
                    SELECT ColA
                        , Date
                        , ColB
                        , SUM(Volume) as lft
                        , CONCAT(EXTRACT(Month FROM `Date`),'-',EXTRACT(Year FROM `Date`)) as monthYear
                    FROM Table2 bdhav 
                    WHERE CAST(Oct_DateTran as DATE) >= '2020-11-01'
                    GROUP BY ColB, ColA, Date
                    ORDER BY ColB, Date ASC
    ) b 
    on sub1.ColA = b.ColA 
    AND sub1.monthYear = b.monthYear
    AND sub1.ColB = b.ColB
    and sub1.lift_date = b.lifted_date
   ) as sub3


+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| ColA     | ColB | Date       | monthYear | MeasureA | runningTotal |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Reston   |  B   | 2020-11-02 | 11-2020   | 500      | 500.0        |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Reston   |  B   | 2020-11-03 | 11-2020   | 0        | 500.0        |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Reston   |  B   | 2020-11-04 | 11-2020   | 1000     | 1500.0       |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```